# Linq query for top parents by number of childs, including this number

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

In my model, there are entities `Article` and `Tag` in many-to-many relation through table `ArticleTag`.
I want to select "trending tags" - tags with most articles in last X days, and I want this count too.

Basically, I need help creating EF Linq query equivalent to this SQL query, with ideal result being  `Dictionary<Tag, int>`

```
SELECT TOP 50
    t.Id, t.Name, count(*)
FROM ArticleTag at
JOIN Article a ON a.Id = at.ArticleId
JOIN Tag t ON t.Id = at.TagId
WHERE a.DateCreated > '2019-10-01'
GROUP BY t.Id, t.Name
ORDER BY count(*) DESC
```

Can this be done without having `ArticleTag` as `DbSet` in DbContext (since it is not really an entity, and I dont need it besides this query).

Comment: All EF Core versions before 5 require an entity for the many-to-many table. Which version are you using? Many-to-many was added in [EF Core 5 RC1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-5.0/whatsnew#many-to-many)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use navigation properties for this query and do not need to know anything about `ArticleTag` table.

```cs
var query = 
   from a in ctx.Articles
   from t in a.Tags
   where a.DateCreated > someDate
   group t by new { t.Id, t.Name } into g
   orderby g.Count() descending
   select new 
   {
      g.Key.Id,
      g.Key.Name,
      Count = g.Count()
   };

var result = query
   .Take(50)
   .ToDictionary(x => new Tag { Id = x.Id, Name = x.Name }, x => x.Count);
```

Comment: [Only EF Core 5](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-5.0/whatsnew#many-to-many) allows many-to-many relations without mapping `ArticleTag`